# in R: how to take value from i+1th row of 1 dataframe and subtract from every row in i+1th column of 2nd dataframe

Tags: r, loops

Note that the actual dataset is 1000s of columns and 100s of rows so I am looking for a way that does not require that i manually name either columns or rows.

With a dataset that has similar structure as follows:

```
subvalues <- c(1:10)

df <- data.frame(x = rpois(40,2), y = rpois(40,2), z = rpois(40,2), q = rpois(40,2), t = rpois(40,2))
```

call the rows of subvalues SVa, SVb, SVc...
call the rows of the dataframe's columns Xa, Xb, Xc... Ya, Yb, Yc... etc.

What I am trying to build is the following: A function that takes first the first cell of `subvalues` (SVa) and subtracts it from every row in column X (Xa, Xb, Xc, etc.), 2nd to take the 2nd cell of `subvalues` (SVb) and subtract it from every row in column y (Ya, Yb, Yc, etc.)

What I have so far is:

```
res <- numeric(length = length(x))  
for (i in seq_along(x)) {  
  res[i] <- xpos - [**SVi+1**] 
}  
res
```

I need to figure out the 'SVi+1' loop and how to properly do the loop-within a loop.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: `length(subvalues)` is 10 whereas `nrow(df)` is 40. How do you subtract rows after 10? Also, it is better to give a reproducible example using `set.seed` and show the expected output to make the example clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example dataset you provide won't work, because you need the same length for `subvalues` and the number of `df` columns.

After some modifications, here is an example. You don't need to extract the value from subvalues, as it's just a substraction.
Note that I've saved df in tmp, to modify this data.frame without loosing your initial data. Also, if the entire data.frame is numeric, consider using matrix, which can save you time.

```
subvalues <- c(1:5) # Note here the length 5 for the 5 columns of df.

df <- data.frame(x = rpois(40,2), y = rpois(40,2), z = rpois(40,2), q = rpois(40,2), t = rpois(40,2))
tmp <- df

for(i in seq_along(subvalues)){
  # print(subvalues[i]) 
  tmp[,i] <- tmp[,i] - subvalues[i]
}
```

`tmp[,i]` is a vector returning the `i` column of the data.frame, and so you can substract a value to a vector, and save it in it's initial place.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `replicate` to create a matrix of same dimensions as `df`, and do subtraction afterwards, i.e.,

```
dfout <- df - t(replicate(nrow(df),subvalues))
```

such that

```
> dfout
    x  y  z  q  t
1   0  1 -1  2 -4
2   0  0  0 -2 -1
3   1  1 -2 -2 -3
4   3  0 -2 -3 -2
5   0  0  0 -1 -1
6   3  1 -2 -2 -3
7   3 -2  0 -2 -5
8   1  0 -3 -3 -4
9   1  1 -2 -3 -2
10 -1  1 -2 -2 -4
11  0  0 -2 -2 -3
12  0  2 -3 -4 -2
13  2  0 -1 -4 -2
14  0 -1  1 -2 -4
15  2 -2  0  0 -4
16  1 -2  0 -2 -1
17  2 -1 -1 -2 -3
18  5  0 -1 -2 -2
19  0  0  0  2 -3
20  2  0 -1 -2 -1
21  3  2 -1 -1 -4
22  0 -1 -2 -2 -4
23  1  0 -2 -3 -1
24 -1 -1  3 -3 -3
25  0  0 -1 -1 -1
26  0 -1 -2 -2 -4
27 -1  0 -3 -3 -2
28  0  1 -1 -1 -2
29  3 -2  1 -4 -1
30  0  2 -1  0 -3
31  1 -1  2 -2 -2
32  1  1  0 -2 -4
33  1 -1 -2 -3 -5
34  0 -1 -1 -2 -1
35  2  0 -2 -2 -4
36  1  2 -3 -3 -3
37  2  2  0 -2 -5
38 -1 -1 -3 -4 -2
39  2  1 -1 -3 -4
40  1  3 -1 -3 -2
```

**DATA**

```
set.seed(1)
subvalues <- c(1:5) # Note here the length 5 for the 5 columns of df.

df <- data.frame(x = rpois(40,2), y = rpois(40,2), z = rpois(40,2), q = rpois(40,2), t = rpois(40,2))
```